# how to post the data with out click on checkbox in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I have form where the select boxes are there and select all option, i want to post all the data without click on check boxes, i dont want to view this  page, mean if user go to signup page the data will already selected by default how can i do that wothout any view?
this is my view code

```
   <?php v_start($this);?>

<?php
    #if(element exits of controller-action)
    echo $this->element('validations/users/signup');    
?>

<script>
    function toggleChecked(status)
        {   
        jQuery(".new-checkbox input").each( function() {
                jQuery(this).attr("checked",status);
                }
            )
        }
</script>
<h1><span style="color:CornflowerBlue"><?php echo __l('Step1');?></span></h1>

<?php
$form = $this->FormManager;
echo $form->create('User',array_merge($form_options,array('default'=>true)));
?>

<table width = "100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $form->input('',array('id'=>'mark-all','onclick'=>'toggleChecked(this.checked)','type'=>'checkbox','label'=>'Select All Products' ));?>

                <?php echo $form->input('product_id', 
                                array(
                                    'multiple'=>'checkbox',
                                    'options'=>$products,
                                    'div'=>false,
                                    'class'=>'new-checkbox'
                                )   
                            );
                ?>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <?php 
echo $this->FormManager->end(LBL_BTN_NEXT);
?>

        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i dont want this page, the user will select the data by default.
 this is my controller code

```
        $products   =   $this
                    ->User
                    ->ProductsUser
                    ->Product
                    ->find('list',array(
                                'fields'    =>  'product_id,name',
                                    'conditions'=>array(
                                                'Product.is_visible'=>true
                                                )                       
                                        )
                            );
    $this->set('products',$products);
    if($this->request->is('post'))
        {   
            $this->Session->write('signUp.signUpProduct',$this->request->data['User']);
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'signup_product'));
        }       
}
```

how can i do that, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your English is making this difficult to understand. You mention select boxes but your code renders check boxes, not select boxes. Also, you mention that you want to post data that the user selects by default, but you want to do this with no form. How does the user select the data you want to post if there is no form? Is the data coming in via Javascript? I am sure I can help you. Just clear up your question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The attr() doesn't take true or false as an argument.

```
jQuery(this).attr("checked","checked"); // Correct usage of attr()
```

Although I think attr is deprecated for the favorable prop() method.

```
jQuery(this).prop("checked",status);
```

Which indeed does take a true/fales argument. :)
Hope this helps.